# RailsTutorial, Micoroposts - push to Heroku not working fully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm following Rails [Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:2.4), creating a micoroposts app and pushing to Heroku. I'm able to get everything working locally, but the push to Heroku, I get no error messages, but the link myurl.heroku.com/micoroposts gives me the message, "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

I have successfully added the following to my Gemfile (and run bundle install), per the tutorial advice, but no luck:

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :group => :development

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the gem requirements on several lines:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite-ruby', '1.3.2'
```

And don't worry too much about the group => development, Heroku takes care of db connections for you.

When you did `heroku create` it would have told you an application name 'some-name-you-typed-in', so your url would be http://some-name-you-typed-in.heroku.com to see if the application starts.